# Import not working inside wrapper function

Tags: python

So, basically my python wrapper is not working because it's not identifying an import statement I used at the start of my code. Here's my code:

```
# Decorator para imprimir o tempo de execução de uma função
import functools
import time 

def timer(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def timer_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.perf_counter()
        value = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.perf_counter()
        time = end_time - start_time
        print(f'Finished {func.__name__} in {time:.4f} secs')
        return value
    return timer_wrapper

@timer
def some_func(n):
    time.perf_counter
    for i in range(n):
        sum([ j*2 for j in range(n)])

some_func(121)
```

Here's the exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decorator.py", line 22, in <module>
    some_func(121)
  File "decorator.py", line 9, in timer_wrapper
    start_time = time.perf_counter()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment
```

Oddilly enough, it works inside other functions(see some_func()).

What's going on? My python version is 3.8.10

Comment: Writing `time = end_time - start_time` makes `time` a local variable and therefore **not** a reference to the `time` module (which, when you do `import time` at the top of the file, *becomes a global variable*). This means you encounter the problem described in the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the function body, you can't use `time` as both as a global variable:

```
start_time = time.perf_counter()  # line 1 of the function
```

And as a local variable:

```
time = end_time - start_time  # line 4 of the function
```

In order to compile the code of the function, Python has to determine what the local variable names are. The presence of the assignment statement above makes `time` into a local variable at *function definition time*. This means that it's already considered a local variable when the first line of the function is executed, even though it hasn't been assigned to yet.

Here is a minimal reproduction of the problem:

```
>>> import time
>>> def foo():
...     t = time.time()
...     time = t
... 
>>> foo.__code__.co_varnames
('time', 't')
>>> foo()
# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment
```

Instead, use a different local variable name, like `elapsed`. The answer on the duplicate suggesting to use a global statement is not a good answer here.